# psgraph: using \psdot changes origin?

Tags: pstricks

I have the following minimal example of a document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-8,-8)(8,8){8cm}{8cm}
\pnode(0,0){P}

\psdot{P}

\psline(1,0)(1,-1)
\psline(-1,0)(-1,-1)

\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

If I compile this on my computer then what i get is: two lines, one starting from (-0.5, 0) to (-0.5, -1) and the second one goes from (1.5, 0) to (1.5, -1) so the origin was moved by 0.5 somehow. The interesting this is: the following document compiles correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-8,-8)(8,8){8cm}{8cm}
\pnode(0,0){P}

\psline(1,0)(1,-1)
\psline(-1,0)(-1,-1)

\psdot{P}

\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

So the command `\psdot{P}` causes the origin to move...

Can someone explain that to me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: I know, I know... but I could not resist... I was truly amazed. Im sorry :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `\psdot{P}` which is expanded by PSTricks to `\psdot(0,0){P}` which prints the dot *and* outputs the P which moves the currentpoint to the right. What you want is

```
\psdot(P)
```

It expects *only* the coordinates. If they a missing it will be `(0,0)`